# How to send a DataFrame using Selenium in python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I'm trying to send the following DataFrame using Selenium into the text field of a Capital Gains Calculator website (http://www.cgtcalculator.com/calculator.aspx).

```
   B  01/12/2000  BARC   3000   4.82  15    72.3
   B  02/12/2000  BARC   5000  4.825  15  120.62
   B  03/09/2002   VOD  18000  3.040  10  273.60
   B  15/01/2003   BP.   5000  3.750  10   93.75
   B  24/03/2003   BP.   3000  3.820  10   57.30
   S  14/04/2003  BARC   6000  5.520  15    0.00
   S  23/02/2004   VOD   9000  3.620  10    0.00
   S  24/02/2004   VOD   9000  3.625  10    0.00
   S  15/07/2005   BP.   8000  6.280  10    0.00
   B  22/01/2007   BP.   5000  5.500  10  124.20
   B  22/06/2009   BP.   2000  5.020  10   50.20
   S  24/12/2012   BP.   5000  4.336  10    0.00
```

So far I'm able to send each column separately but the problem is that the columns appear one underneath the other in the text field. For the calculator to work, I would need to maintain the format of the DataFrame. Is there a way to do this?

This is what I've done so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/Test.csv")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.cgtcalculator.com/calculator.aspx")

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("TEXTAREA1")
inputElement.send_keys("\n".join(df. iloc[:, 0]),"\n")
inputElement.send_keys("\n".join(df. iloc[:, 1]),"\n")
inputElement.send_keys("\n".join(df. iloc[:, 2]),"\n")
inputElement.send_keys("\n".join(df. iloc[:, 3].astype(str)),"\n")
inputElement.send_keys("\n".join(df. iloc[:, 4].astype(str)),"\n")
inputElement.send_keys("\n".join(df. iloc[:, 5].astype(str)),"\n")
inputElement.send_keys("\n".join(df. iloc[:, 6].astype(str)),"\n")
driver.find_element_by_id("Button3").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("Button1").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy enough to send the df to the clipboard and paste w/selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'B', 'B', 'S'],
 '01/12/2000': ['02/12/2000',  '03/09/2002',  '15/01/2003',  '24/03/2003',  '14/04/2003',  '23/02/2004',  '24/02/2004',  '15/07/2005',  '22/01/2007',  '22/06/2009',  '24/12/2012'],
 'BARC': ['BARC',  'VOD',  'BP.',  'BP.',  'BARC',  'VOD',  'VOD',  'BP.',  'BP.',  'BP.',  'BP.'],
 '3000': [5000, 18000, 5000, 3000, 6000, 9000, 9000, 8000, 5000, 2000, 5000],
 '4.82': [4.825, 3.04, 3.75, 3.82, 5.52, 3.62, 3.625, 6.28, 5.5, 5.02, 4.336],
 '15': [15, 10, 10, 10, 15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
 '72.3': [120.62, 273.6, 93.75, 57.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 124.2, 50.2, 0.0]})

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.cgtcalculator.com/calculator.aspx")

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("TEXTAREA1")

df.to_clipboard(index=False, sep='\t')

inputElement.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')

driver.find_element_by_id("Button1").click()
```

Output

```
SUMMARY INFORMATION

Year    CapitalGain      Exemption    UsePrevLosses   TaperRelief   ChargeableGain      Tax*
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
03-04   14175         7900      0       0       6275        1059
05-06   19848         8500      0       0       11348       2060
12-13   -5284         10600     0       0       0       0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question, however, when I run your code, no data seems to be pasted in the text field of the webpage. Is there a line missing after `df.to_clipboard` by any chance? thanks!

Comment: OK just realised it was `inputElement.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, 'v')` on a mac - thanks a lot!